# Mokito Unit test NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.keySet()?

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to do `unit` testing using `mockito` for below JSONobject.

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(JsonString);
obj.put("newEntry","UserId")
Set<String> objKeySet = obj.keySet();
```

**Added Dependency**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Error**

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.keySet()Ljava/util/Set;
```

My question is why mokito runner is not able to find method `keySet()` however put mehod is working fine. how can i fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check imported class is the one you intended to import, check the finally resolved dependency is one you expected in the pom

Comment: import org.json.JSONObject; is the correct intend. but still i am getting same error

Comment: As mentioned check which version is finally resolved. In that version of jar this method may not be there

Comment: my code is compiling successfully and running perfectly. but while unit test case getting fail and throwing error

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solutions please...

Answer (score 1):

I could able to fix it by adding the exclusions sections to pom.xml file

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It might be helpfull for others if you could include the version of `spring-boot-starter-test` you used. I also assume you used different json dependencies in your project somewhere (probably like mentioned in the original question), so it would also improve your answer if you could mention those separate artifacts (including version number) in the displayed pom.