java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.json.JSONObject.keySet()
I've been migrating code from an API to another one developed in Java 14, Spring Boot
public Object getJsonIgnoreCase(JSONObject json, String clave) {return json.keySet().stream().filter(k -> k.equalsIgnoreCase(clave)).findFirst().map(json::get).orElse("");}

This one throws the following error:
Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.json.JSONObject.keySet()'
    at biz.belcorp.ssicc.leadingconsultant.service.InterfaceGenerateFileTextPlain.getJsonIgnoreCase(InterfaceGenerateFileTextPlain.java:137)
    at biz.belcorp.ssicc.leadingconsultant.service.InterfaceGenerateFileTextPlain.write(InterfaceGenerateFileTextPlain.java:80)
    at biz.belcorp.ssicc.leadingconsultant.service.InterfaceUploadService.uploadFile(InterfaceUploadService.java:164)
    at biz.belcorp.ssicc.leadingconsultant.service.IntGenerInterfaceService.lambda$1(IntGenerInterfaceService.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Of courser I've defined the dependency on POM project:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>   

I've tried to describe my problem. I'm looking for a solution or/and an explain why does this ocurr?

You are using spring and also maven. Spring and maven know exactly what you want to do, and you are using those because they know exactly what you want to do: you want to rely on a deus ex machina, and this is not gona work. Get back to the roots: what are your jar-files, where are they found on your box, what files are in there, in what version and what methods do not match your application?

At runtime you are using a different org.json.JSONObject than you use at compile time. Do a mvn dependency:tree and check that no other JSON libraries (e.g. the google android one) are being included.

Once you find the duplicate JSON dependency, here's an example of how to revise your pom.xml to exclude the unwanted version.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316989/mokito-unit-test-nosuchmethoderror-org-json-jsonobject-keyset
